# Session was Invalidated -- Alamofire

Tags: swift, session, networking, alamofire

i have used the singleton pattern for networking call but one issues is faced can anyone help me to solved this issue  the session was invalidated

> Session was invalidated without error, so it was likely deinitialized unexpectedly. Be sure to retain a reference to your Session for the duration of your requests.

and my networking wrapper is

```
public static let shared = NetworkingClient()
    private var requests = [ApiRequest]()
    private var completedRequests = 0
    private var session: Session!
    func InvalidateSession () {
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            Alamofire.Session.default.session.getAllTasks { (tasks) in
                    tasks.forEach{ $0.cancel() }
                }
            } else {
            Alamofire.Session.default.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { (sessionDataTask, uploadData, downloadData) in
                sessionDataTask.forEach { $0.cancel() }
                uploadData.forEach { $0.cancel() }
                downloadData.forEach { $0.cancel() }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my Api Call the secanrio is increase quantity then crash the alomofire i want to stop the send request multiple request i want to send request api only 1 time

```
func gasEstimation(chain_Id: Int, contractAddress: String, fromAddress: String, toAddress: String, tokenId: String, contractType: String, quantity: String) {
        let apiRequest = [ApiRequest(type: .get, path: "gasEstimation?chainId=\(chain_Id)&contractAddress=\(contractAddress)&from=\(fromAddress.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))&to=\(toAddress.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))&type=\(contractType)&quantity=\(quantity)&tokenId=\(tokenId)")]
        NetworkingClient.shared.performRequest(requests: apiRequest) { path, data, error in
            if data != nil {
                let json =  JSON(data!)
                let gasTokenModel = NftTransferModel(json: json)
                self.presenter?.onReceiveFee(estimationFee: gasTokenModel,error: nil)
            }else{
                let error = JSON(error!)
                self.presenter?.onReceiveFee(estimationFee: nil,error: error["message"].stringValue)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please update your code when you are calling an api ??

Comment: @Chandaboy i updated the code please check

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here.

1. The use of `Session!` indicates you're operating on an optional value, which seems unnecessary. Also, if you're replacing this value, this is likely the cause of the invalidation error, as the `Session` that was replaced will invalidate when it's deinited.
2. You have `private var session: Session!`, yet you use `Session.default` to cancel all of your requests. This is incorrect, you need to cancel requests on your local `session`.
3. Manually cancelling all of the requests like you are is unnecessary and may break Alamofire's internal assumptions. Never interact with the `URLSession` instance directly. Instead, `Session` has a `cancelAll()` method you can use to do the same thing.
4. Alamofire doesn't support iOS 9, so that version condition check is unnecessary.
5. I suggest you transition to using `Decodable` for your JSON parsing, it's far simpler and Alamofire has built-in support for it.